# Getting "java.io.IOException ExifInterface only supports saving attributes on JPEG formats on" *.jpeg load instead .jpg

Tags: java, cordova, android-camera, cordova-plugins

Getting error from [cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/tree/master/src/android) when adding image.jpeg from library. All fine when adding image.jpg

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: ExifInterface only supports saving attributes on JPEG formats.
W/System.err:     at android.media.ExifInterface.saveAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1770)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.camera.ExifHelper.writeExifData(ExifHelper.java:163)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.processResultFromCamera(CameraLauncher.java:556)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.onActivityResult(CameraLauncher.java:824)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterfaceImpl.onActivityResult(CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:152)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onActivityResult(CordovaActivity.java:358)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7235)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4320)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4367)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)

2018-11-29 13:23:53.790 31265-31265/com.bei.bemobile W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Have you got a solution? actually, I am looking for .webp format.

Comment: unfortunately, no